# Select range of file unix

Tags: regex, file, unix, filter

I have a script that analyse a set of files that have the same prefix and a different index: prefix0, prefix1, ... prefix100000. I usually run this script as:

```
./script prefix*
```

in this way I use all the 100000 files. How could I use only the first 1000 or 2000 files as script argument? Is there a regular expression that do it? Is there a general way regardless the index of the files I want to use (i.e from file prefix0 to prefix1000 or from prefix50 to prefix500)?

Comment: Where's the code of `./script` ?

Comment: A glob is not a regular expression.  For the example you give, you could do `./script prefix[12]???`, but this would also match the filename `prefix1aaa`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use regular expressions in a glob, but you could do:

```
  ./script $( seq 5 50 | sed 's/^/prefix/' )
```

to edit files prefix5 through prefix50  (if you have `seq`; if not, use `jot`)

However, if you're going to do this, you probably should consider invoking the script in a loop instead of trying to pass all the arguments at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the shell construct of [].

Following your example of ranges:

`./script prefix[50-500] 
 ./script prefix[0-1000]`

It will execute all the scripts named within the range.

Have fun!

http://mylinuxbook.com/8-examples-of-wildcards-in-bash/